# fortran code won't compile in MinGW

Tags: windows, compilation, mingw, fortran

I am using the newest available version of MinGW, with fortran packages.
My code compiles perfectly in linux, but in windows I get the following error:

" ... undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_real'| "

and a bunch of similar ones. How can I fix this?

edit:
the above error comes from this line:

```
write(chpar,600) H3,T1,Omega0,dOmega,N
```

other lines that produce errors are:

```
call random_seed (SIZE=Nseed)
call random_seed (PUT=seed(1:Nseed))
```

edit2:
I use the compiler options -gfortran -lgfortran, and it won't compile.

thanks

Comment: There isn't enough data in here to conclude anything with certanty. Could you please edit your question to include the code in question (if possible) and the compiler errors /or any output it gave/? If it is really the compiler settings problem a small program should produce errors of similar kind.

Comment: It seems like you do not use gfortran as your linker. When you use something else (ld, gcc) you should add -lgfortran option.

Comment: I know I'm late on this, but What are the datatypes of H3,T1,Omega0,dOmega and N?  and what format is the label 600?  To me it looks like a typecast gone awry.

Comment: It likely has more to do with your IDE than your operating system. Check the configuration to make sure its set up correctly.